# Profiler that attaches to running processes?

Tags: c, performance, gdb, profiler, d

I need a good profiler for both Windows and Linux (they don't have to be the same one; separate recommendations for each OS are fine) that can attach to an already running process that was not compiled in any "special" way and give me statistics on what functions the process is spending most of its time in.  I have some long running scientific code and I want to get snapshots of where it's spending most of its time at various stages of execution, **and be able to get the results without having to run the whole program start to finish**.

The compiler I'm using (Digital Mars D) comes with an instrumenting profiler.  It's way too slow for the jobs I'm running.  Since I'm only interested in identifying major bottlenecks, I want something fast and easy to use, even if it's only roughly accurate.  Ideally it should also be able to profile all threads simultaneously and give me an aggregate report.

On Linux, I've been using GDB  as a poor man's sampling profiler (pausing my app a few times and seeing what function it's in).  Basically, a more automated version of this is what I'm looking for.

One last requirement:  On Linux it has to be easy to install without root privileges, since I'm going to be running it on a server that I don't have root access to.

Edit:  While the code was written in D, D's compilation model, etc. is similar enough to C's that tools written for C should work fine.

Answer (score 31):

If you have a fairly recent kernel you can use `perf`:

```
perf record -p <pid> -g
```

...then `perf report` once you've gathered enough samples.

Comment: seems like `perf` is not available anymore on kernel 5.0.0

Comment: @cduguet: It is still available, in fact it is distributed in the Linux source tree (in `tools/perf`).

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for oprofile:

http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This looks great except that I'd have to convince my sysadmin to install a kernel module, which is probably not gonna happen.

Comment: That's a shame. :( Without help from the kernel, there's no way to get reliable profiling information.

Answer (score 2):

For Linux, try [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/). ALso, for rough work, [`lsstack`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lsstack/) is useful for finding bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but [xProf](http://h3.gd/code/xfProf/) was written specifically for D. It's a statistical profiler.

Comment: xProf appears to use [the gprof model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343).

Comment: The link to the hg repository on that page is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Performance Recorder (WPR) and Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA) are best profiling tools for Windows 8 and above. Xperf works really well on Windows 7.